# How to search a string in a column of an Excel file

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

I have an excel file which have a column name (`name`) which has the following entries:

1. vipin
2. vipin
3. vipin
4. vipin

I want to count the entries in the `name` column where my string is `"vipin"`. Using OLEDB data provider.

Comment: Actually i have no idea how to do search particular string in excel .  String strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source="d:\vipin.xls" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();          
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT count(*) FROM [Sheet1$] where name ="vipin", strConn);

Comment: take out the count part and just work with the DataSet (ds) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you pulling the excel sheet into a DataTable like so?

```
OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(   
            "select * from [" + worksheetName + "$]", con);   

        con.Open();   
        System.Data.DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();   
        cmd.Fill(excelDataSet);   
        con.Close();
```

If so just iterate through the DataRows like normal.

```
foreach(DataRow dataRow in excelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows){
    if(dataRow["columnName"].ToString().Equals("vipin")){
       count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: its showing an error when i run this code"foreach (var dataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows())". it says (system.data.datatble.rows can't be used like a method.

Comment: @vipinkatiyar: Try `foreach (var dataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)`

Comment: @Otiel i have done it already but next error is dataRow["Name"].It says can,t apply indexing.

Comment: hi Otiel its works but we have to place"foreach (DataRow dataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)".

Comment: var is .net 4.0. For previous frameworks you do have to use DataRow.